# Difference between .dat and .txt in c++

Tags: c++, file, record

I am using `.txt` files in my program for reading and writing records (records contains both text and numerals). Recently i came to know that `.dat` file also can be used like `.txt` for file operations. I would like to know the difference between the two and the advantages and disadvantages of one over another.

Comment: It's better to mention C++ in your question Tag

Comment: File extensions just help the OS to know what program should it use to open that file. It doesn't tell anything about the structure of the file. You can have a `.txt` file that contains binary data or a `.dat` file with text data in it

Comment: File extensions are just a hint for Programs which can parse files easier. They don't have fixed meaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Text files or `.txt` files are a bit hard to parse in programs and easy to read. whereas `.dat` is usually used to store data that is not just plain text.

Generally .txt files contains letters, characters and symbols which is readable.

`.dat` is binary text file in which data is not always printable on screen.

Answer (score 3):

The extension of a file is a helper so that the operating system (or user) can choose the appropriate program to open it. The actual file contents do not matter. There are some conventions what extensions to use but there is nothing from keeping you to use any arbitrary extension for your files. For instance you can rename a .jar file to .zip-file and be able to open the file with pkunzip.

So for C++ the extension does not matter, but for you as a programmer it may give a hint of the file contents i.e. open it in text or binary mode.

Answer (score 1):

In most languages like C/C++ there is no difference what is your file type in file operations(Read, Write or Edit).

just if you want to work with binary files you should open them in binary format because if you reached `\0` in text file it's file end. Dat files are binary too!

If you want to store and read some data, XML file and somtimes DAT files are better because of good libraries to read them. they don't need hard parsing of Text files

Comment: -1, albeit the first sentence is correct, the rest is wrong-ish or misleading. `\0` does not mark the end of a file, it's just that conventionally is not included in text files (and EOF characters do not exist on any recent OS, it's just a flag used by some C functions). "DAT" does not specify any particular file format (and often is used for text data), so of course there's no particular library used to write/parse them. XML just provides you a syntax for some tree-like structure, and even parsing it with a library is often way more complicated than an ad-hoc text or binary file.

Comment: (Just to remark: the point of XML is extensibility and interoperability, *not* ease or speed of parsing - in these aspects, it's one of the *worst* formats)

Comment: open any text file in a hex editor and see if there's any '\0' in it